# How do I query a sub collection in EmberFire?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, emberfire

I am currently trying to fetch data from FireStore using EmberFire. Right now, my collection is /users and in there I store a user ID. Under the user ID I create another subcollecion, containing an array called /presets.

I want to use EmberFire to retrieve the presets for the currently logged in user. How can I tell this to EmberFire?

I tried fetching other data using EmberFire and it worked fine. For example, fetching documents from a collection works perfectly fine, I just have never used sub collections. Hence the question.

What I would like to achieve is something like

```
this.store.query('/users/pLvAT0TSbAjsnXoVmMF7yEG3mkW2/presets')
```

to get to the data stored in (collection users) -> (document pLvAT0TSbAjsnXoVmMF7yEG3mkW2) -> (collection presets).

Of course I would like to then use the traditional workflow to turn the documents in presets into views.

Right now, I am only able to work with a single collection. Nested collections are not something I am able to work with.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

A general answer would be:

```
this.store.find('users', 'pLvAT0TSbAjsnXoVmMF7yEG3mkW2').then((user)=>{
  return user.get('presets');
})
```

But it assumes some things done "the Ember way":

1. There's `User` model
2. There's a `Preset` model
3. There's a `hasMany` relationship between `User` and `Preset` like this:

```
// app/models/user.js
import DS from 'ember-data';
const { Model, attr, hasMany } = DS;

export default Model.extend({
  presets: hasMany('preset', { subcollection: true })
});
```

Although the current version of Emberfire (v3-rc2) doesn't work pretty well with Subcollections, you'll be able to fetch records, but not create or update one.

Sources:

- [Emberfire guides](https://github.com/firebase/emberfire/blob/master/docs/guide/relationships.md) (right now kind of empty, but hopefully someday it'll have good info)